# tablesorter Plugin Add Column Dynamic

Tags: tablesorter

I am Using my project **Tablesorter Plugin**, I am Dynamic Added and Removed COLUMN and Rows,   Also Delete Column and Rows,

Remove Column Rows And Add Rows Sortable Function Working Perfectly,

But Add New Column Dynamic Then Table Sorter Not Working.

Please Help how i solve This Problem.

I got The Following  Error

```
**TypeError: h[list[i][0]] is undefined 

h[list[i][0]].addClass(css[list[i][1]]);**
```

I Create Dynamic Column in Table, and I am Click The New Column Header.

Answer (score 1):

The original tablesorter (tablesorter.com) is will not work correctly if you add or remove columns, even if you trigger the "update" method. It is only designed to work with changes to the `tbody`.

You can use my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) to work properly in your case by triggering the [`"updateAll"` method](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#updateall) as follows:

```
var resort = true, // re-apply the current sort
  callback = function(table){
    alert('table updated!');
  };

// let the plugin know that we made a update, then the plugin will
// automatically sort the table based on the header settings
$("table").trigger("updateAll", [ resort, callback ]);
```

Please note, the [`sortList` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortlist) does update from its initial setting and always contains the current sort; but, it will not apply to the same column (it's a zero-based index) if a new column is inserted to the left of that sorted column.